# HTML5: Position: absolute or/and margin breaks my code

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to make a slideShow kind of thing but I have problems with margin and/or position absolute when I try to reposition buttons When I write:

```
<style="position: absolute; left: somepx; etc:"></style>
```

or

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: somepx; etc:"></div>
```

my code that is in div breaks For example My button has this code :

```
<button class="slide" onclick="plusDivs(-1)" 
style="margin: 265px;">&#10094;</button>
```

I have jsCode here :

```
var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }
```

I ALSO have some text They are in class: mySlides

When I run the code The button is repositioned but it doesnt work

Same thing with margin

Help please

Comment: please answer ??

Comment: Sec. I am currently looking into this but I dont know if I can solve the problem. Also `<style="position: absolute; left: somepx; etc:"></style>` is wrong. You probably mean `<style>position: absolute; left: somepx; etc:</style>`

Comment: poste your whiole html and make question clear !

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: sry thats right

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to tell from the code you posted, where the mistake is because it's not included. Please check these things:

- The script must be loaded before the html if you want to use `onclick`
- Your Slide-Elements don't have the class `mySlides` (maybe you gave it accidentaly to the container)

Alternatively you can use an Event on the button instead, because the script you posted works fine:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    plusDivs(-1);
});
```

**Here is a complete Snipptet**

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  plusDivs(-1);
});

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  };
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50px;"></div>
<div class="mySlides">1</div>
<div class="mySlides">2</div>
<div class="mySlides">3</div>
<button id="btn" class="slide" style="margin: 8px;">&#10094;</button>
```